# Browsers do not send Kerberos authentication token on Linux

Tags: django, linux, firefox, kerberos, spnego

I am trying to configure Kerberos authentication for an application I develop. When opening the app from a browser (Chrome or FF), I get the 401 response from server with WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate header, but the browsers do not send the negotiation token back to the server.

### Details

My platform: Linux Mint

I've got ticket for my user using

```
kinit myusername@MYREALM.RU
```

I can verify the ticket is valid with `klist`.

If it's relevant, `myusername` for the realm differs from my linux user name.

I've set `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` and `network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris` in Firefox to `sd.mydomain.ru` (I've also tried `.mydomain.ru`, `http://sd.mydomain.ru`). I've also set `network.negotiate-auth.allow-non-fqdn` to `true`.

Opening the `sd.mydomain.ru:8000` sends an AJAX request to `sd.mydomain.ru:8000/accounts/kerberos/login/` which responds with 401 code and WWW-Authenticate header. Nothing happens afterwords.

I've tried to set

```
$ export NSPR_LOG_MODULES=negotiateauth:5
$ export NSPR_LOG_FILE=/tmp/moz.log
```

then ran Firefox from that console. After opening the page the log is empty.

I've tried using Chrome, running it as

```
google-chrome --auth-server-whitelist="sd.mydomain.ru:8000"
```

with the same effect as in Firefox (401 response from server, and nothing happens).

### Some more details

If this can help, my application is a Django app using django-kerberos library. It uses the keytab file, acquired running a command (on Windows)

```
ktpass -princ HTTP/sd.mydomain.ru@MYREALM.RU -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -out django.keytab
```

The file was created with a warning:

```
For the account to work withing a Windows domain, the principal must be
mapped to an account, either at the domain level (with /mapuser) or
locally (using ksetup)
If you intend to map HTTP/sd.mydomain.ru@MYREALM.RU to an acoount through
other means or don't need to map the user, this message can safely be ignored.
WARNING: pType and account type do not match. This might cause problems.
```

The [instruction](https://pypi.org/project/django-kerberos/) for configuring django-kerberos does not mention user mapping, so I assumed, it is not needed.

To test my app, I saved the keytab file locally and ran the application using this file. I've edited `/etc/hosts` to route `ed.mydomain.ru` to 127.0.0.1.

Also, I connect to KDC through VPN (which should have no effect to anything, just mentioning).

I've tried everything I could think of and googled for hours, so any suggestions about where to dig next would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The browser isn't sending the ticket. Since you're doing an async web call you may have to the `withCredentials` property on the request before the browser will allow it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Comment: Thanks @Steve for the suggestion. The request is made by kerberos library. It didn't set the withCredentials to true, so I've edited the library js code for test, but it gave no effect. Also, if I make the request to the authorization endpoint directly without AJAX, the result is still same.